# Get Default Printer ShareName w/ Powershell in Variable

Tags: powershell, automation, printers

I'm trying to store the current default printer in a variable in Powershell to add this name back using a different print server. The command I'm using to store this name is:

```
$default_printer = Get-WMIObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | where{$_.Name -like "*\\*"} | select sharename
```

Which will provide me with:

```
sharename
---------
WI_IT-Test
```

Issue arises when I try and setup the new printer with the command:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\printsrv01\$default_printer
```

I believe when I'm setting the variable in the beginning it's also storing the string " sharename --------- " as well as the name of the Printer.
How do I **only** grab the printer name and not the...

```
sharename
 ---------
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you are wanting to use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter when selecting. This selects the value only and not the key/value object. i.e. `... | select -ExpandProperty sharename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-Object` will create a `PSCustomObject` of key/values. I'd recommend two options:

1. Use `ExpandProperty` to return only the value of `sharename`. i.e. `... | select -expandproperty sharename`.
2. the `sharename` property. i.e. `Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\printsrv01\$($default_printer.sharename)"`

In your case you're wanting a single property so the first option is good. If you are selecting multiple properties the latter is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. The "\\printsrv01\$($default_printer.sharename)"  minus the quotes was the trick in this case. :) Thanks again!